# Ajax and php delete error in WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, wordpress

This is my first attempt at using Ajax and PHP to delete a row from MySQL. I'm getting the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function delete() on a non-object in /home/insightd/public_html/dev/wp-content/plugins/id-ffui/lib/delete.php on line 10

Everything is working as it should but the row is not deleting.

The delete part of the HTML form:

```
  echo "<div class='ffui-media-item'>";
  echo "<div class='ffui-delete' align='center'><a href='#' id='" . $media_item['ID'] . "' class='delbutton' title='Click To Delete'>X</a></div>";
```

The jQuery/Ajax part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
   $(".delbutton").click(function(){
    //Save the link in a variable called element
    var element = $(this);

    //Find the id of the link that was clicked
    var del_id = element.attr('id');

    //Built a url to send
    var info = {"id" : del_id };
      if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Record?")) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "<?php echo plugins_url('id-ffui/lib/delete.php') ?>",
          data: info,
          success: function(){   
          }
        });
        $(this).parents(".ffui-media-item").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" }, "fast")
          .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
      }
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

And the delete.php file:

```
global $wpdb;
global $ffui_db_version;

$ffui_items = $wpdb->prefix . "ffui_items";

if($_POST['id']) {
  $id = $_POST['id'];
    $wpdb->delete( $ffui_items, array( 'ID' => `$id` ) );
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the code you show is the entirety of delete.php, then $wpdb hasn't been instantiated. You need to load the core WP files first:

```
require_once( dirname( dirname( dirname( dirname( __FILE__ )))) . '/wp-load.php' );
```

The rest of your code comes after this. And if this is the case, you don't need the "global" commands, since you're not operating inside a function or object.

Here's a [great explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860577/wordpress-wp-load-php) of wp-load.php:

Comment: Perfect! I found this and used it. $absolute_path = explode('wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
 $wp_load = $absolute_path[0] . 'wp-load.php';
 require_once($wp_load);

Comment: I just edited the answer to match what another plugin developer did, as shown on the linked "great explanation" page.

Answer (score 2):

Incorrect backticks:

```
$wpdb->delete( $ffui_items, array( 'ID' => `$id` ) );
                                           ^---^--
```

PHP does not use backticks in its code. It should be just `'ID' => $id`

As for the actual error message, you don't appear to have included the wordpress libraries, so `$wpdb` doesn't actually exist.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to include the wordpress libraries in my php file?