# I want to make a popup in wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

i make the popup in html but i don't know how to integrate it in the wordpress...

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'>
```

Are you 18 years of age or older?

Comment: What you have tried related to the popup ? you just posted the jquery google cdn source only, so be clear with your question befoe post

Comment: anyway try this https://wordpress.org/plugins/anything-popup/

Answer (score 0):

You have to include wp-load.php to use WordPress API, and its location is relative to your plugin path.

check this out : 
[Wordpress wp-load.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860577/wordpress-wp-load-php)